# Is there a way to avoid a "method initialize redefined" call in ruby?

Tags: ruby, gtk

I have code like this:

```
class Gtk::Entry

  def initialize(foo = '')
    super()
    call_a_custom_method_here(foo)
  end

  def call_a_custom_method_here
  end

end
```

Gtk is ruby-gtk, the module Gtk.

I try to modify this existing widget, called Gtk::Entry.

I need to hook the initialize call to also call a custom
method.

The above will trigger a warning though:

"method initialize redefined"

Is there a way to avoid the initialize-method redefined
problem?

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Matz:

> IIRC, warning
>   was caused when you replace an existing method without making any
>   alias to the original.

If you still need to call the original, alias it then chain it at the end of your new `initialize`. If you don't, use `remove_method`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to hook the initialize call to also call a custom method.

But that's not what you are doing. You are *overwriting* `initialize`. It is gone. You are not hooking it.

> Is there a way to avoid the initialize-method redefined problem?

Yes. Hook the method, don't overwrite it.

```
module GtkEntryInitializeHook
  def initialize(foo = '')
    super()
    call_a_custom_method_here(foo)
  end

  def call_a_custom_method_here
  end
end

class Gtk::Entry
  prepend GktEntryInitializeHook
end
```